# ¿Como puedo en el gráfico de torta "pie chart", al hacer click aparezca titulo?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Sobre highcharts.

```js
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
  tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        color: '#FF0000',
        allowPointSelect: true,
        data: [1,2,3,4]
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Al hacer click

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ponle titulo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @gbianchi Ok...

Comment: Intenta cambiar a `true` el valor de `enabled` dentro del atributo `tooltip`: `tooltip: {enabled: true}` mas info: [tooltip](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.tooltip), este evento se dispara con un evento `over` y no justamente con un `click`

Comment: @ÁngelHernández Si vi, es dificil.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
  tooltip: {
        enabled: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        color: '#FF0000',
        allowPointSelect: true,
        data: [1,2,3,4]
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Esto es lo que puedes hacer con el hover. Cuando la utilicé en su día, no venía con lo que pides de serie, ni individualizando cada 'pie'. Puedes dejar una leyenda permanente y los datos con hover. Te dejo el ejemplo aunque lo habrás probado supongo.

Comment: osea puede datalabers.